# Conectar mysql mediante la ip real

Tags: mysql, xampp

Buenas, quiero configurar el server mysql del xampp para que pueda ser conectado por ejemplo por "navicat" usando el ip real del  server (152.34...). Solo puedo hacerlo con el ip 127.0.0.1 en la misma pc.

Comment: Comprueba el firewall del servidor por ejemplo, pero esto no es una pregunta de programación y si no aportas más datos...

Comment: me da el error 2003 cuando intento conectar mediante el ip externo. Como hago para que el server mysql permita el acceso

Comment: El error 2003 está documentado aquí: http://faq.webyog.com/content/23/15/en/error-no-2003-can_t-connect.html y en este hilo, hablan del tema https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673530/error-2003-hy000-cant-connect-to-mysql-server-on-127-0-0-1-111 en dónde dicen lo siguiente: edita el fichero my.cnf de tu server y comenta la línea en dónde pone bind-address = 127.0.0.1 usando el símbolo # delante de la misma.